# Integral with respect to a multivariable function and change of variables

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

Suppose you have a function

$$\omega=-\int_0^Q[\alpha_1(x,y,z)+\alpha_2(x,y,z)+\alpha_3(x,y,z)]dQ'$$

where $Q=g(x,y,z)$ and $Q'$ is a dummy variable. Lets say you want to change the variable of integration to $x,y,z$, how would one go about this? For $\alpha_i=f(x)$ and $Q=f(x)$ this is straightforward $\int f(x)dg(x)=\int f(x)g'(x)dx$, however, I don't see the generalization to multiple variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things to comment on here. Firstly, $Q$ is a function of 3 variables, so you can't change from an integration over 3 variables to an integration over 1 (except by integrating over two variables). I think you're trying to say "integrate over all values of $Q$ between 0 and a given value, which I've also called $Q$" – but if $Q$ is defined in 3d then that means integrating over a volume, not an axis. Introducing vector calculus in full here is not going to be possible but I'll try to answer your question briefly.

Volume integrals are typically notated
$$\int_V f(\mathbf{x}) dV$$
Note that $V$ is NOT a limit – it's saying that the integration should be over a volume in space, where vectors $\mathbf{x}$ are defined. Once you choose a parametrisation for $\mathbf{x}$, for example $(x,y,z)$, you can then express this as three integrals, e.g. something like
$$\int_0^a\int_0^b\int_0^c f(x,y,z) dx dy dz$$

Changing variables in 3d is a little more complicated than in one dimension. The chain rule – which you quoted in your question – still applies, but the derivative function becomes a linear map from 3 to 3 dimensions. This is typically expressed in a matrix of partial derivatives known as the **Jacobian**. You can read about it on Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant).

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Indeed your assumption that I'm integrating over all values of Q between 0 and a given value of Q. I should have used a dummy variable $\overline{Q}$. So basically, in physical terms, integrate a function of pressure over all pressure values between 0 up to a final pressure P. Where the pressure is a function of $x,y,z$. I've had vector calculus many years ago so I will look back at my notes (to be honest, I've completely forgot to think about vector calculus in this case). Thank you for the insight.

Comment: So I am still a bit confused. If we have the integral from 0 pressure to the actual pressure, $\int_0^Pg(x,y,z)dP'$ , and $P=f(x,y,z)$, then by the nested integral definition, if one of the components $x$, $y$ or $z$ is zero, the complete integral is zero. Physically this is not correct, as in this case we still have a pressure, but this pressure is due to the other two components. For example, assume $P=x+y+z$ and if $z=0$, there is still a pressure over which we can integrate.

Comment: It would help me if you could explain what you were trying to do – what is $g$, and what is the physical meaning of what you're trying to do? I have studied fluid dynamics (a little while ago to be fair!) so the terms will probably have a meaning to me.

Comment: The way you're defining the integral is a bit odd. The volume is defined by the pressure varying. So if the pressure doesn't vary, then there is no volume i.e. one of these integrals is zero; but then dP is zero. I'm fairly certain this isn't what you mean to do but it's what's alluded to by your notation at the moment.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. So I am trying to calculate the effective work of inserting component $x,y,z$ into a system from a reservoir. The $\alpha's$ represent the "free volume" for each component in the system and the pressure is the pressure of the reservoir. So in order to calculate the overall work you basically integrate all the individual free volume contributions, which depend on the pressure, which in turn depends on the concentration of $x,y,z$, between 0 pressure in the reservoir and the final reservoir pressure. Sorry for the ambiguity in my notation.

Comment: Thus $g$ is a measure for the free volume in the system. ^Ran out of space.